# Laravel AuthController not updating function body

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, xampp

For a school project I am trying to remove Eloquent from the core of my project (have to work directly with DB, cannot use ORM).

I am now trying to modify the create function of the AuthController, but it does not seem to be updating. (Using XAMPP with PHP7.)

As you can see I tried to replace the User::create default with the DB::insert statement inside of AuthController's create function.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
  return DB::insert('INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,birthday,gender,email,password) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)',
    array(
      $data['firstname'],
     $data['lastname'],
     $data['birthday'],
     $data['gender'],
     $data['email'],
     bcrypt($data['password'])
    )
  );

    // OLD FUNCTION BODY:
    /*return User::create([
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
    ]);*/
}
```

But now I keep getting:

**FatalThrowableError in AuthController.php line 71: Fatal error: Call to undefined method App\User::create()**

I believe that the function needs more than DB::insert, as it says, that it should return a new instance of the User object, but at the moment I cannot even test what this would do as it is still trying to call the old function body. I have even deleted the User::create section alltogether.

Is this a XAMP thing? I had no problem updating and saving other files of this project, but this controller does not make it through it seems like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean Laravel cache. Then use this:

```
return DB::insert(array(
     'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
     'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
     'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
     'gender' => $data['gender'],
     'email' => $data['email'],
     'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
    )
  );
```

If you will still get the error, please post contents of 71th line of `AuthController.php`

Comment: I restarted my computer and the changes took effect for some reason. Not sure what the cause was, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning two entirely different thing.

```
return DB::insert
```

vs

```
return User::create
```

See what User::create returns and go from there.